# How to get only the time of 9:00 to 21:00 between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two timestamps e.g '20-Nov-2010 20:11:22' started and ended.  Now I want to calculate the time between 9:00 to 21:00 which is 12 hours.

The input will be two dates like '10-Nov-2010' and '20-Nov-2010' `start date` and `end date`

```
componentid   starttime               endtime                result  
3             13-Nov-2010 10:00:00    13-Nov-2010 21:00:00    11:00  hours  
5             14-Nov-2010 09:30:00    14-Nov-2010 22:00:00    11:30  and
3             15-Nov-2010 08:20:00    15-Nov-2010 20:00:00    11:00  minutes
4             16-Nov-2010 08:00:00    16-Nov-2010 23:00:00    12:00
                                                          sum 45:30
```

Now from examples I only want the hours and minutes in between 9:00 and 21:00 the time which comes in this range from 10-Nov-2010 and 20-Nov-2010.  I don't know how to do that in Oracle SQL - can you please explain how to do it?

Comment: Are you after the row-by-row result column, or just the final SUM? The SUM format is H:MM where H can be hundreds or thousands, or some other?

Answer (score 1):

This is for the final sum

```
select
    trunc(Mi/60) || ':' || right('0' || mod(Mi,60), 2) Total
from
(
    select sum
    (
        (
        case when endtime-trunc(endtime) > 21.0/24 then 21.0/24 else endtime-trunc(endtime) end
        -
        case when starttime-trunc(starttime) < 9.0/24 then 9.0/24 else starttime-trunc(starttime) end
        ) * 24 * 60
    ) Mi
    from tbl
    where starttime >= to_date('10-Nov-2010')
      and endtime < to_date('20-Nov-2010') + 1
) M
```

Answer (score 0):

How would you do it by hand?

- You need to determine the minimum (earlier) of the end time on the day and 21:00 on the day to establish the end point.
- You need to determine the maximum (later) of the start time on the day and 09:00 on the day to establish the start point.
- The difference between these two values is the time you want.

Reducing that to SQL requires a knowledge of the time-manipulation functions for Oracle - this is one of the areas where each DBMS has its own set of idiosyncratic functions and rules and what works on one will not necessarily work on any other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  componentid,
    starttime,
    endtime,
    (
     CASE WHEN (endtime> TRUNC(endtime+ 21/24)) THEN TRUNC(endtime+ 21/24)  ELSE endtime  END - 
     CASE WHEN (starttime< TRUNC(endtime+ 9/24)) THEN TRUNC(starttime+ 9/24)   ELSE starttime END
    )*24  result    
  FROM <YOURTABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of providing yet another way of doing time arithmetic, I'll use a view with interval arithmetic. (PostgreSQL, not Oracle.)

```
CREATE VIEW experimental_time_diffs AS 
 SELECT component_id, start_time, end_time, 
   case when cast(end_time as time) > '21:00'
        then date_trunc('day', end_time) + interval '21' hour else end_time end - 
   case when cast(start_time as time) < '9:00'
        then date_trunc('day', start_time) + interval '9' hour else start_time end
   AS adj_elapsed_time
   FROM your_table;
```

And you can sum on the view's column "adj_elapsed_time".

```
select sum(adj_elapsed_time) as total_elapsed_time 
from experimental_time_diffs;
```

Comment: Your case will count 59 minutes of time that should not be counted if your end time is 21:59.  You need the equivalent of: `EXTRACT(HOUR TO MINUTE FROM end_time) > INTERVAL '21:00'`; you might need to subtract midnight ('00:00') from the result of the EXTRACT to convert it to an interval, or you might need to use `... > TIME '21:00'`.  Or simply use `> 20`.  It gets trickier if the end time changes to 21:30, though.

Comment: You're right. Looks like it's easier to cast the timestamps as time.